# How to create conditional CellValueFactory for TableView?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `TableView` with a column that needs to display one of two values from my data object.

In the MCVE below, I have a `Person` object that may or may not have a `nickname` property. This `nickname` can either be populated, empty, or `null`.

---

**Person.java:**

```
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class Person {

    private IntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private StringProperty nickname = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Person(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String nickname) {
        this.id.set(id);
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
        this.nickname.set(nickname);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName.get();
    }

    public StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName.set(lastName);
    }

    public String getNickname() {
        return nickname.get();
    }

    public StringProperty nicknameProperty() {
        return nickname;
    }

    public void setNickname(String nickname) {
        this.nickname.set(nickname);
    }
}
```

**Main.java:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Simple Interface
        VBox root = new VBox(10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        // Build the simple TableView
        TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Person, String> colId = new TableColumn<>("ID");
        TableColumn<Person, String> colName = new TableColumn<>("Name");

        // Set the cell value factories
        colId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("id"));
        colName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("nickname"));

        // Add the column to the tableview
        tableView.getColumns().addAll(colId, colName);

        // Populate the tableview with a couple of samples
        tableView.getItems().addAll(
                new Person(1, "John", "Williams", null),
                new Person(2, "Marty", "McFly", "Chicken"),
                new Person(3, "Emmett", "Brown", "Doc"),
                new Person(4, "Hans", "Zimmer", "")
        );

        // Add the table to the scene
        root.getChildren().add(tableView);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

---

What I need is a `CellValueFactory` that will use the `nickname` property if it has a value, but the full first and last name of the person if `nickname` is empty or null.

**How do I create a conditional `CellValueFactory`?** I am assuming it requires creating a new Callback function for the factory, but I am not sure how that works.

Comment: use a conditional binding based on the value of the cellDataFeatures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @kleopatra [hints at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52669045/how-to-create-conditional-cellvaluefactory-for-tableview#comment92269614_52669045), one way to do this is to create a conditional binding in the `cellValueFactory`. This is done via [`Bindings.when(ObservableBooleanValue)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#when(javafx.beans.value.ObservableBooleanValue)).

```
nameCol.setCellValueFactory(features -> {
  var firstName = features.getValue().firstNameProperty();
  var lastName  = features.getValue().lastNameProperty();
  var nickname  = features.getValue().nicknameProperty();

  return Bindings.when(nickname.isEmpty())
      .then(firstName.concat(" ").concat(lastName))
      .otherwise(nickname);
});
```

The [`isEmpty()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/StringExpression.html#isEmpty()) binding considers `null` values to be empty.

> Note: If the value of this `StringExpression` is `null`, it is considered to be empty.

Comment: I like this answer. I have a question though, how is the performance on this when you have 100s of thousands of rows?

Comment: Glancing at the implementation, the factory seems to be called whenever it's possible the value of a cell has changed. There are very little actual cells displaying at any given time, though, since `TableView` is a virtual control. I guess if the values change frequently or the user scrolls wildly this factory could be called often and thus create many throwaway bindings but I'd expect the GC would be capable of keeping up. However, I haven't tested anything. If this presents a problem one could try caching the bindings—don't know how effective that'd be.

Comment: @trilogy Bindings are implemented with weak listeners, so can be garbage collected. Plus, the cell implementations go to great length (usually ;) to remove their own listeners on the observable value. In sum, there's no strong reference to the old value once the cell is re-used. At Slaw: yeah, it's possible to model the data to view needs, but shouldn't. What if f.i. the displayName must be localizable? Typically there are myriads of different display requirements - and that's why clean separation of concerns (view vs. data model) is so extremely important

Comment: @kleopatra I was hesitant to put the second option, as I agree with you. However, for an entity like `Person` I figured one could argue the behavior could be put in the model. Especially since we're dealing with proper names (which, as far as I know, wouldn't be localized). You could call the property something like `preferredName` to make it less connected to the view. Or do you still think this behavior should be separate? If so, I'd like to remove that part of the answer to avoid encouraging bad practices.

Comment: we can certainly argue back and forth, so for fun of it I'll go on: there's nothing inherent in the ordering of first relative to last name - see Chinese f.i. - or another requirement might be to add a middle name or its abbreviation, or another requirement might want to start with the last name followed by the comma separated first name or ... that's why such formatting is left to the view :)